# Bash Script - batch rename files in current directory with preview

Tags: beginner, bash

I have written the following script to automate my frequent usage of `rename`.
This saves me from always typing the whole command to the command line as well as doing a dry run with `-n` for testing before applying the pattern.

```
#!/bin/bash

 if [ ! -d ~/.script-history ]; then
     echo -e "Folder .script-history does not exist and gets created... \n";
     mkdir ~/.script-history\
      && { echo -e "created folder: ~/.script-history \n"; }\
      || { echo -e "could not create folder: ~/.script-history \n"; }
 fi

 history -r ~/.script-history/rename
 set -o vi
 search=""
 replace=""

 echo -e "Please enter token to be replaced: "
 read -e -r search
 history -s "$search"
 echo -e "Please enter replacement: "
 read -e -r replace
 history -s "$replace"
 history -w ~/.script-history/rename

 value=$(rename -n "s/$search/$replace/g" ./*)

 echo -e "$value"

 lines=$(echo -en "$value" | wc -m)

 if [ "$lines" -gt 0 ]; then
     read -p "Do you want to apply changes? [Y]es [n]o " yn
     case $yn in
         [yY]* ) echo "renaming files...";\
                 rename "s/$search/$replace/g" ./*\
                 && { echo "success :-)"; }\
                 || { echo "failed :-("; };;
         [nN]* ) echo "no changes have been made."; exit;;
         * ) echo "Are you kidding me???";;
     esac
 elif [ "$lines" -eq 0 ]; then
     echo -e "No matches found for <$search> !"
 fi
```

- For making it easier to adjust or reuse the changes done with the script, I added a history, while the first part checks if the folder exists where I save my histories for script files. I do not quite understand this line `set -o vi` but it is working.
- For me as a beginner it was quite tricky to get the script recognizing whether there are changes to be applied or not. My workaround here is the `$lines` variable, where I count the output of chars and then process with 
  `"$lines" -gt 0` or `"$lines" -eq 0`.

One of the questions I have is about the usage of the `A && B || C` pipe. I use it quite frequently in my scripts, where [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) reports the following:

> SC2015: Note that A && B || C is not if-then-else. C may run when A is true.

The other output of [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) is:

> SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes.

I think it is ok, since the user is only expected to input `YyNn`. While I use the script on a daily basis, is the coding sufficient or where can it be improved?

The disadvantage of the script is that you have to type in both *search* and *replacement* before it checks if there are matches. An improvement could be to add a function that checks for that and returns to the *search* input when there are no matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Checking if a value is not empty

This is a very complicated way to check that `value` is not empty:

> ```
> lines=$(echo -en "$value" | wc -m)
>
> if [ "$lines" -gt 0 ]; then
> ```

This is equivalent:

```
if [ "$value" ]; then
```

#### Avoid `echo -e`

It's good to avoid all flags of `echo`, such as `-e`,
because they are not portable.
Instead of this:

> ```
>  echo -e "Folder .script-history does not exist and gets created... \n";
> ```

I recommend to add a second empty `echo`:

```
echo "Folder .script-history does not exist and gets created..."
echo
```

#### The concern about `A && B || C`

Shellcheck raised an issue here:

> ```
>  rename "s/$search/$replace/g" ./*\
>  && { echo "success :-)"; }\
>  || { echo "failed :-("; };;
> ```

The issue is that if `rename` succeeds but then `echo success` fails,
the `||` will get executed.
You can ignore this issue, because in the unlikely event that the first `echo` fails, the second (after the `||`) is likely to fail too, so it won't matter.
If you want to be pedantic/bullet-proof, then you have to spell out a proper `if-else` statement instead of the `&& ... ||` chaining.

In any case, the command can be simplified without the grouping:

```
rename "s/$search/$replace/g" ./* \
&& echo "success :-)" \
|| echo "failed :-(" ;;
```

I also added spaces in front of the `\` before the line breaks,
to make it perfectly clear that the argument before the `\` is not being continued on the next line.
Without that, this point would be ambiguous, making the script a bit harder to read.

#### The concern about `read` without `-r`

If the user input contains `\`, it may not get preserved.
That's hardly ever intended,
and probably you would not want that either.
As a rule of thumb,
it's good to always use `read -r`.

Comment: Thanks allot for your detailed feedback. The use of the history is when you run the script multiple times you can get to the old input via the _arrow up_ key. So lets say you renamed `xx1` to `file`, then you decided you want to rename `file` to `audio` then you can just select the `file` with the _arrow up_ key and so on. I found that pretty useful. If I would just append the commands I used to a file, how could I call them so they could be reused in the input?

Comment: @nath I see your point. I removed that section.

Comment: how would you go with the `elif [ "$lines" -eq 0 ]; then` if there was no use of the `$lines` variable anymore?

Comment: @nath `value` is either empty or not. So you don't need an `elif`, use a simple `else` instead

Comment: I just tried: `elif [ ! "$value" ]; then` would work too, but thanks again, I'm going to use your suggestion with`else` simplifying the code!

Comment: @TobySpeight fair enough, clarified, thanks ;-)